# How to disable a clippy lint for a single line / block?

Tags: rust, rust-clippy

I am getting some Clippy lints that look like this:

```
warning: methods called `to_*` usually take self by reference; consider choosing a less ambiguous name
  --> src/helpers/mod.rs:29:32
   |
29 |     pub fn to_vec_sorted<U, F>(self, mapper: F) -> Vec<U>
   |                                ^^^^
   |
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#wrong_self_convention
```

I have no problem dealing with this lint, I just picked it because it doesn't show any proprietary code. Suppose I had a really good reason why I needed to name the function this way, and also that Clippy is integrated into my CI, so I need to have zero Clippy errors / warnings.

Is there a way to disable a Clippy lint *for a particular line or code block*, analogous to `@SuppressWarnings("whatever")` in Java? I feel like there must be, but I can't find any examples of doing this in the documentation.

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy#allowingdenying-lints

Comment: Without context it's hard to say for sure, but probably the best way to get rid of the warning, is to fix the code and rename the method to `into_vec_sorted`.

Comment: @mcarton If you read the prose it points out that this lint is easy to solve, it's just present to give a minimal example. I'm looking for a general way to disable a lint in a narrow scope, which was provided in an answer below.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The [docs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy#allowingdenying-lints) state you can allow or deny lints.

```
#[allow(clippy::wrong_self_convention)] pub fn to_vec_sorted<U, F>(self, mapper: F) -> Vec<U>
```

And ,if you want to disable *all* <sup>1</sup> of them:

```
#[allow(clippy::all)] pub fn to_vec_sorted<U, F>(self, mapper: F) -> Vec<U>
```

---

<sup>1: `clippy:all` doesn't actually allow *all* lints, rather everything contained by `correctness`, `suspicious`, `style`, `complexity`, `cargo`, and `perf`. This means no `pedantic` or `nursery` lints..</sup>

Comment: Just for dumb and confused people like me: "allow" doesn't mean to allow clippy to warn about this, but to allow that lint to be ignored..