# How to prevent cargo clippy from analyizing generated prost files

Tags: rust, rust-clippy, prost

I am using prost to generate rust classes for protobufs. I want clippy to ignore these generated files and I'm having trouble figuring out how to make clippy ignore them.

In my lib.rs file, I have

```rust
pub mod modes {
    #[allow(clippy)]
    include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/modes.rs"));
}

#[allow(clippy)]
pub mod vehicle_features {
    include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/vehicle_features.rs"));
}
```

However, I still get clippy warnings for both the modes.rs and vehicle_features.rs files. How do I ignore these modules / files in clippy, without modifing the files at all.

EDIT: based on a below suggestion, I changed the code to read:

```rust
pub mod modes {
    #![allow(clippy::all)]
    include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/modes.rs"));
}

pub mod vehicle_features {
    #![allow(clippy::all)]
    include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/vehicle_features.rs"));
}
```

This works when running `cargo clippy` but not when running `cargo clippy -- -W unwrap_used` does anyone know why? How can I make it work when I add additional warning arguments to clippy?

EDIT2:

I found the answer here: [How to disable a clippy lint for a single line / block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402812/how-to-disable-a-clippy-lint-for-a-single-line-block)

"clippy:all doesn't actually allow all lints, rather everything contained by correctness, suspicious, style, complexity, cargo, and perf. This means no pedantic or nursery lints.."

So I had to add
`#![allow(clippy::all, clippy::pedantic, clippy::nursery)]`

Answer (score 5):

You need to allow `clippy::all`. `#[allow(clippy::all)]` outside the module, or `#![allow(clippy::all)]` inside it.

Comment: This seems to work when running `cargo clippy` however, if I run `cargo clippy -- -W clippy::unwrap_used` it doesn't work. Do you know why?

Comment: @Connor I don't really know but I guess the more specific warning takes priority over the generic `clippy::all`, or the command line takes priority over the source code.